# Switch between sets of input of Snakemake workflow without starting from the head

Tags: workflow, snakemake

I am building a Snakemake workflow to analyze exome sequencing data.

The workflow needs an input file set of **one sample**; sometimes, I need to work on other samples, but how can I do that I can pick up the forward sample when I make small modification to my workflow?

I don't want Snakemake to run the entire process from the beginning because it would take considerable time. I hope it can restart from what I‘ve changed. It's frustrating that running the process on the second sample seems to overwrite the records of the first run, so I can only start analyzing the first sample from scratch.

I am trying to copy the `Snakefile` somewhere else and prepare a new `configfile` to it. I don't think it is a good idea, for building the conda envs for every `Snakefile` costs me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's frustrating that running the process on the second sample seems
> to overwrite the records of the first run, so I can only start
> analyzing the first sample from scratch.

This looks like a problem with the way how the paths are defined in your rules. Do you use wildcards in your outputs and inputs to distinguish samples? Paths should be derived from the sample name, so it would be unique and therefore not rewritten when running workflow for other sample.

Let's have a simple example with 2 samples: A, B.

```
SAMPLE_TO_USE = "A" # taken from the config or some other way

rule all:
    input:
        result=f"results/{SAMPLE_TO_USE}.txt",

rule do_something_with_sample:
    input:
        fastq="data/{sample}.fastq",
    output:
        result="results/{sample}.txt",
    ...
```

When you provide in the config that you want to use sample `A`, the first rule (`all`) will requests to produce "results/A.txt". Then when you want to use sample `B`, the first rule (`all`) will request to produce "results/B.txt".

Secondly, you can use `snakemake --conda-prefix {DIR}` to install conda envs in `{DIR]`. This way you can share installed conda envs from one run to other runs simply by using one central {DIR} for all workflows.